# $H^k= \{f \in P^k : \Delta f = 0\}$?

Tags: spectral-theory, spherical-harmonics

Let $P^k=$homogeneous polynomials of degree $k$ in $x$, $y$, $z$, $k=0, 1, 2, \dots, $, i.e. $P^k= \text{Span} \{x^{k_x}y^{k_y}z^{k_z} : k_x+k_y+k_z=k\}$. This is maybe a silly question, but I am not able to figure out what is the spherical harmonics of that kind of set? In other words, what would be another way to express $H^k= \{f \in P^k : \Delta f = 0\}$, where $\Delta$ is the usual Laplacian operator?

Thanks!

Comment: No need for "span" in the defintion of $H^k$, since operator $\Delta$ is linear.

Comment: Hint: Work recursively. $H^0 = P^0, H^1 = P^1$, and the Laplacian applied to a homogeneous polynomial is again a homogeneous polynomial of degree two lower.

Comment: I know that "the Laplacian applied to a homogeneous polynomial is again a homogeneous polynomial of degree two lower" because $\Delta : P_k \to P_{k-2}$ is a surjective map. However, among the polynomials $p_k \in P_k$, which one should be $\Delta p_k=0$ and what their forms?

Comment: @JeanCharrue As $\Delta$ is a linear map, and you have bases of $P^k$ and $P^{k-2}$, it is a linear algebra exercise to find a basis of $\ker\Delta$ in $P^k$.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I'd like to get an explicit form for $H^k=\ker \Delta_k$. I know for example that $H^2=\text{span}\{ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dxy+exz+fyz : a+b+c=0\}$, but I could I generalize that?

Comment: This may not be the sort of thing you want, but... it has been known for a long time that $H_k$ is an irreducible repn of the orthogonal group, so is necessarily generated by any single non-zero total-degree-$k$ harmonic polynomial, such as $(x_1+ix_2)^k$... Or by the "zonal" spherical harmonic, which is invariant under $O(n-1)$.